# Wallpaper Breach in window xp

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-xp

I have applied group policy for my Company Wallpaper. But in window xp, if i right click on images in web browser and than select Set as wallpaper, than the wallpaper changes. ( please see the below print-screen )
[image]

Can you please guide me, how should i stop this breach.

Domain Controller OS = Windows Server 2008 R2 Std Edition, 
Client OS = window XP

Answer (score 3):

To make this also apply to Windows XP and older computers, you also need to set the wallpaper in Active Desktop settings.

This is documented in [Microsoft KB327998](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327998).

> To resolve this issue, specify an Active Desktop wallpaper setting in
>   Group Policy. To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click **Start**, click **Run**, and then type **gpedit.msc**.
> 2. Under **Local Computer Policy**, expand **User Configuration**, expand **Administrative Templates**, expand **Desktop**, and then click **Active Desktop**.
> 3. Double-click **Active Desktop Wallpaper**.
> 4. On the **Setting** tab, click **Enabled**, type the path to the desktop wallpaper that you want to use, and then click **OK**.

Active Desktop itself may remain disabled, but the wallpaper also has to be set here in order for Set Desktop Background to not work. Keep in mind that the option won't be grayed out, but will stop working.

Comment: Hi Michael Hampton,the Above option is not working, still the user are able to change the wallpaper. Please guide & Thanks for your reply.